# Why isn't my canvas working?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt, illegalstateexception

I am creating a game canvas but for some reason I can't get it to work correctly. I get an InvalidStateException and I haven't got a clue what is causing it. Can anyone shed some light?

My main entry point...

```
public class GameTemplate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameFrame();
    }

}
```

My JFrame subclass...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {


    public static final short WIDTH = 1024;
    public static final short HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    public static final Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    public GameFrame() {
        super("Game Frame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(size);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        GameCanvas canvas = new GameCanvas(size);
        this.add(canvas);
        canvas.start();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

My Canvas subclass...

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class GameCanvas extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private Thread thread = null;

    private BufferStrategy bs = null;
    private Graphics g;
    private Graphics2D g2d;

    public GameCanvas(Dimension size) {
        this.setSize(size);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            update();
            draw();
            render();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void update() {

    }

    private void render() {
        bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        bs.show();
    }

    private void draw() {
        if (bs != null) {
            g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }
    }

}
```

The error...

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at GameCanvas.render(GameCanvas.java:63)
at GameCanvas.run(GameCanvas.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1) Don't mix Swing (e.g. `JFrame`) and AWT (e.g. `Canvas`) components together without good cause.  In this case, you might render to an image and display it in a label, or extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics)`  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) `Thread.sleep(10);` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the concurrency in swing. What else is there to add a Canvas to if it should not be added to a JFrame?

Comment: *"What else is there to add a Canvas to.."*  Forget the `Canvas`!  Use a `JPanel` **instead**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the frame initializer, in your case:

```
public GameCanvas(Dimension size) {...}
```

You need to invoke the method "frame.addNotify()" e.g:

```
 public GameCanvas(Dimension size) {
    this.setSize(size);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addNotify();
 }
```

Then later down your code, you want to include the code:

```
@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
}
```

This just notifies the frame that you want this class to use the buffer. What you where doing was trying to get the frame to use the buffer to create a graphics type buffer strategy, when the frame didn't know which component's buffer to use for the requested task.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
```

This may be cause when you were calling `createBufferStrategy()` the component must have been hidden.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @Andrew , you are mixing [light and heavy weight](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) components.Rely on default BufferStrategy.As we can see,`Canvas` is not displayable, until you add it to `Frame`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense though because I set the Canvas visibility to true in the constructor and then the buffer strategy was created during the game loop

Comment: @JohnPringle after the exception, your application stops or continues?

Comment: The execution continues, but the canvas isn't visible. I tried adding it to the frame before setting its visibility to true but that produced the same result. Although Andrew suggested I extend JPanel instead of Canvas, I have actually been able to get this to work with a Canvas on a JFrame in the past and I don't understand why it will not work for me this time.

Comment: @JohnPringle But please don't mix both of them.Any problems with JPanel?